# Jump to last prompt in terminal (or tmux)

Tags: terminal, tmux, scrolling

In a terminal, are there any shortcuts to jump to a previous/next prompt? Scrolling up and trying to find the start of a log slows down my workflow.

I'm using iTerm on OSX, but this should be applicable to any Unix terminals. A solution in Tmux would help as well.

Comment: If your hostname is in your prompt, you could reverse search to cycle back that way...

Comment: Pipe to `less`.

Comment: Note: this year there is a [feature request](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3064) for built-in support in tmux.

Answer (score 7):

Inside tmux v2.4+
 ([relevant commit](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/76d6d3641f271be1756e41494960d96714e7ee58)), you can define a binding to jump to the last prompts with acceptable reliability:

```
bind-key b copy-mode\;\
           send-keys -X start-of-line\;\
           send-keys -X search-backward " "
```

Where the `" "` is a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) and a corresponding change is made to have you shell prompt contain it (`$PS1` or `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in bash).

It may require special care to set it in the shell prompt and the tmux configuration, as it could be changed to regular space during copy-paste operations (see method with vim in the comments).

Alternatively, you can try your favorite alternative [unicode space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) or anything that occurs rarely in command outputs and that you're ready to accept seeing in your prompt (?).

This could also be a combination of several characters for even less false positives. It's probably better to pick something at the very end of the prompt, though, for easier navigation.

**Credit**:

- https://github.com/salcode/ironcode-tmux/issues/21 for the use of the non-breaking space and the binding. I first thought this could be a use case of the [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) but it did not seem to work.
- [robenk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/324486/robenk) for pointing out that copy-pasting weird character spaces is not always reliable

Comment: Cutting and pasting would not get the non-breaking space character to work for me, but I was able to get it to work using Vim. In insert mode, use `CTRL-k <space><space>` to insert the non-breaking space. Then afterwords, in normal mode, the `ga` command prints the ASCII value of the character under the cursor which can be used to confirm this character is different from other spaces.

Comment: The following tmux bindings will, once you are in copy mode, let you jump backward and forward between prompts with `n` and `p`: `bind -T copy-mode-vi n send-keys -X search-forward " "` and `bind -T copy-mode-vi p send-keys -X search-backward " "` (`" "` should contain a non-breaking space)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `less` to view the contents of the log file, you have the ability to scroll back and forth using the <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> keys (see the `less` manual). You may also perform searches in the output with <kbd>/</kbd> (and <kbd>?</kbd> for backward search).

To view the output from a program in `less`, simply pipe the output to it:

```
$ ./myprogram | less
```

To additionally save the output in a file:

```
$ ./myprogram | tee myprogram.out | less
```

If you press <kbd>F</kbd> while reading a file that's being written to, `less` will behave like `tail -f`. To interrupt this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

With tmux v3.4+, there is now a built-in command just for this, for shells that support OSC 133:

```bash
tmux bind -T copy-mode n send-keys -X next-prompt
tmux bind -T copy-mode p send-keys -X previous-prompt
```

There's also the `-o` option, if you want to jump to the beginning of the command output instead of the shell prompt.