# Does a shortcut exist to auto scroll to the top of a command response in terminal?

Tags: linux, last

Is there a shortcut (keyboard) to automatically scroll back to the beginning of a response to a command?

Example: I open the terminal and type the 'last' command and press enter.
A long lost of previously logged in users appears but I am at the end (i.e. oldest users). Scrolling back up to the top can be a bit of a pain. 
Is there a way to jump to the top of the output of this command?

I checked the man page for 'last' doesn't seem to contain such a function.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/972226/328038) describes something similar for `iterm2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, you'd normally pipe the output into a pager like `less`.

```
$ last | less
```

Comment: Thanks @rusty shackleford i'm new to Linux, i've come across the last command before but never realized I had a use for it until now. It suits my purpose perfectly. For future reference you run the following command $ last | less, the output from last will open in some kind of editor window (I don't know a better  way to describe this). Navigating to the top or the bottom of this open file/window is simple type gg to go to the top and shift+g to go to the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid there is no a general, terminal-agnostic way to do that.
In general, you have to find a way to go back to a previous prompt.  For example, if
you use `GNU screen` you can enter `copy/scrollback mode` with `C-a [`, move one line up, enter `?` and type a part of your prompt.  In
`xfce4-terminal` you can select `Terminal->Find` and then enter a part of
your prompt and press `Previous`.  You don't even have to use mouse to
do that - <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, type your
query and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>. See a possible solution for `tmux` here: [Jump to last prompt in terminal (or tmux)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226731/jump-to-last-prompt-in-terminal-or-tmux).

The only minor drawback of that solution is that your prompt might be
constructed dynamically and might be different after each command but
usually there is a common part that you can use to search for
backwards.

Comment: Please do not leave downvotes without an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Arkadiusz Drabczyk, the answer provided by rusty shackleford (above) is exactly what I was looking for in this instance but I am sure I will need your process for something in the future. I didn't down vote your answer by the way, I appreciate your time and effort.